# Android SeekBar - Change ScrollBar value independently of progress bar

Tags: java, android, user-interface, seekbar

I am trying to use a `SeekBar` to indicate two pieces of information:

1. The threshold for audio recording, which the user can set.
2. The incoming audio level, which the user cannot set.

I would like to use the user touch input to change the `ScrollBar` of the `SeekBar`, indicating the desired threshold.  The progress color bar will be programmatically set by me to show audio level, independently of the `ScrollBar` position, and will not be effected by user input.

I've tried using `SeekBar.setScrollX(int)` and `SeekBar.setScrollY(int)`, but the documentation says that these calls will invalidate the view, and indeed the program does crash when one of these functions is called.

Here is the touchEvent code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
            setScrollX(50); // this causes a MethodNotFoundError
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);                
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and here is the simple test onScrollChanged function that I am using.  Note that the NoSuchMethodFoundError still occurs if this is not overridden.

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int x1, int y1) {
    super.onScrollChanged(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get in logcat?

Comment: I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError.  I even get this when I implement onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int), which is what the docs say is called when using setScroolX(int) or setScroolY(int).

Comment: can u post the code snippet u use to set the scroll value?

Comment: Okay, it's added.  Wish I could be more specific with the NoSuchMethod error, but my logcat is deciding to not output anything right now, so I simply have the debug stack, which is not illuminating :)

Comment: Your class extends SeekBar right?

Comment: Yes, my class extends SeekBar.

Comment: I get the NoSuchMethod when trying view.setScrollX(20) also..